# How do I adding to score a collision?

Tags: iphone, swift

How do I adding to score a collision?

Here is my code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

       func addScore() {
        score = +1

    }

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA

    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.monster != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.naboj != 0)) {

            if let firstNode = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
                let secondNode = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode  {

                    projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstNode, monster: secondNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, switch your line in your fun `addScore` to

```
score = score + 1
```

then all you have to do is call `addScore()` in whichever collision you want to add the score to.

```
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.monster != 0) &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.naboj != 0)) {

        if let firstNode = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
            let secondNode = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode  {

                projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstNode, monster:    secondNode)
                addScore()
}
}
}
```